# Problem with COPY intruction while building docker image with - < Dockerfile

Tags: python, docker, copy, dockerfile

I have 1 folder that contains several dockerfiles, and i want to specify which is the one i want to build.
In this case i'm suposed to use

```
docker build - < Dockefilename
```

But it gives me back errors

```
docker copy failed stat /var/lib/docker/tmp/docker-builder/src/main.py: no such file or directory
```

But. If leave only one dockerfile in the folder, named "Dockerfile", and build exacly the same dockerfile with

```
docker build .
```

It works with no problems.
The error is caused by COPY instruction. While building with - <Dockerfile, i cant copy main.py, while i can do it with docker build .

Edit
It doesn't matter if the copied files are in the same directory as dockerfile, or not. Error occures anyway.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is an expected behaviour.

Quoting the statement from [official doc](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/build/#build-with--).

> $ docker build - < Dockerfile

> This will read a Dockerfile from STDIN
> without context. Due to the lack of a context, no contents of any
> local directory will be sent to the Docker daemon. Since there is no
> context, a Dockerfile ADD only works if it refers to a remote URL.

With `-`, docker build reads from STDIN without context causing problem while adding or copying the files during the build process. In case of `docker build .` command, the context is used and hence the copying/adding files works.

Also if you want to specify a specific dockerfile during the build, then use [-f option](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/build/#specify-a-dockerfile--f).